# git push in vscode terminal now opens a browser

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

In the past, whenever I entered `git push` in the integrated terminal in VSCode, I would sign in like normal with my username and password (also entered in the terminal), but now when I use the integrated terminal it opens a browser window and has me sign in with GitHub.

This issue does not persist when using stand-alone terminal.

I have no idea what caused this change as I have not changed anything regarding my workflow or extensions.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
git config --global user.name "<YourUserName>"

git config --golbal user.email "<YourEmailAddress>"
```

If you happen to be using Windows, then you will be provided with a Windows Credential Manager. You can save your username and password using the credential manager(it should get saved automatically provided windows credential manager is enabled). Then, if you use the git push command afterwards, the credential manager will automatically input your username and password(provided your git config user.email matches the username saved in the credential manager)

This however will expose your email id to those visiting your repository(if it is public). You can prevent that by using the 'no reply github username' that will be displayed in the email section of your profile settings in github.
Just set git config --global user.email with your respective no reply username to hide your email id from those viewing your repository.

Please note:
This only works for Windows(as mentioned above). I do not know how it works for macOS or Linux so please bear with me.

Please visit(This is the best option and directly answers your questions):

https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences
(check the first 5 sections within this page)

Alternatively, you may visit the following website to access possible answers to your question(Only visit the following two if the first option didn't work out):

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

You may also visit:

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: I do happen to be working in Ubuntu Linux, though your suggestion does perform the same in Linux as it does in Windows. 

However, I believe this is a "feature" of VSCode and not of git, since it does not behave the same in my standalone terminal.